# Troubling with wordbress nginx on ubuntu

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, nginx

I installed nginx, php5, and wordpress on ubuntu 12.04 (as well as other services).

I followed step by step digitalocean's tutorial, somewhere in the middle of the process i realised i want to switch from root user to 'foo' user and i chown-ed all relevant files and directories.

I finished the tutorials and straggling for many hours trying to figure why i get 403 forbidden error.

i launch the service with foo user using sudo.
all the workers are running under foo apart from the master which is running from root.

Update:

It seems i have a problem with the landing page which doesn't recognise it should look for index.php, when i type xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/index.php (as full path to the php file) i get this error:

> The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable.
>   Please try again later.

This error pops only on php files, on regular html / txt it works fine.

any suggestions why:

1. default landing is not directed to index.php
2. can not open php files

Update:

So apparently the tutorial in digitalocean had a minor misleading line, i solved the 2nd problem with this nice article: http://www.queryadmin.com/921/connect-unix-var-run-php5-fpm-sock-failed/

Answer (score 0):

for some reason a few lines in the vhost file were commented out. rest of issues were solved as described above updates